# How can I use Office365 to sent SMTP emails from Joomla?

Tags: emails, smtp

Microsoft now requires MFA to be set up to use SMTP.  I don't see an easy way to add a 2FA to Joomla for this process.

Is there a way to do this in Joomla to send SMTP via the standard Joomla way of doing things?

Comment: I could be wrong but can you use option 1 here https://shorturl.at/sCMT4 along with an app password as described here https://shorturl.at/hAK17

Comment: The first one won't work as they state at the top of the article, they turned it off in January 2020.

Comment: I missed that part, I'm out of ideas so good luck.

Comment: No worries, thanks for trying to help